# Ignoring wsimport in maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, wsdl, maven-install

I am using maven (install) and receiving errors like these

[image]

I want *maven install* to skip the *wsimport* part. Is it possible? I have seen [only another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17026135/7674438) that suggests using episodes, but I need a more straigthforward solution, something like [tests skipping command](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html).

Comment: Show us the part of the POM where wsimport is defined.

Comment: I don't wanna have to comment parts of pom.

Comment: I just want to have a look at the POM to better see what can be done.